Is there a way to tell slicer which part of the model should be a continuous line?
I have a model that has an extremely thin place, only one perimeter in width. Slicer moves in the way marked with the red line, creating a join in the very middle of the very visible flat pane. I marked it with a red line on the first picture.
I would prefer if the printer would print the exterior wall first, and leave any joining marks on the interior only, as marked with a green line below. Is there a way to achieve this?
I am using PrusaSlicer and Orca, but I'm ready to try other slicers if they can do it.
Model is cable-cover.stl from the Galileo2 project. Older version, because I have another issue with the current one.


Note: For Cura, Orca and Prusa, Outer / Inner wall is a different distinction. On the pictures, all orange ones are classified as outer walls, and yellow ones are inner. The inner-outer or outer-inner distinction does not change the effect. That's why I am using "exterior wall" and not "outer wall" in my question.

It's not possible to have such fine control over the path generation, as far as I know. (Slicers don't really know what your “exterior wall” is.) In order to get a seamless junction you will need to fit in two extrusion widths, which you could do by either:

Slightly thicken that part of the model on the inside (if this will not create clearance issues). You can insert boxes in PrusaSlicer which might be able to do it.

Use a smaller nozzle.


